# Here.com API format

Tags: here-api

I am pretty new to this so all help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to use Here.com API's and on their example page for Traffic Incidents it has this example:

https://traffic.hereapi.cn/traffic/6.3/incidents.json

?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}

&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

&bbox=37.586,126.969;37.477,127.106

&criticality=minor

When I go to my account all I have are:

1) APP ID

2) API Key

There is nothing labeled "YOUR APP CODE".  Can someone please tell me what they are looking for?  Also when I do get the right info do I replace everything AFTER the '=' sign with these ID's or do I put the data between the curly brackets?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give...

Comment: Can you share the link with example page for Traffic Incidents?

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-incidents- Check out this you can use both api key or appid & appCode, you can use any one if them

Comment: There's also their Authentication Guide: https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

When we log into Developer Portal, we

1. Create a project
2. We then generate an App by clicking on `Generate APP`. This creates your application and shows you application authentication credentials. An `APP ID` is generated for identifying your application.
3. Next, you click on `Create API Key` and you get your `API KEY`.

This `API KEY` is what you will be using for all your API calls and write it wherever it says `{YOUR_API_KEY}` by replacing the complete curly bracket and the content inside it with your API KEY.

For **Traffic API**, see [Traffic Dev Guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/incident-data.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I decided to format your answer a bit nicer, hope you are ok with it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)